# How can I pop-up a cheat sheet in GVIM on command?

Tags: vim, gvim

I know there are lots of cheat sheets for VIM out there, but I hate having to print out so many cheat sheets.

Is there a way I can pop-up a cheat sheet with a shortcut?

I am using GVIM on Windows, so I would prefer something pretty like [this](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html), but a text one would be fine too. I know VIM has a pretty extensive help system, but I haven't found anything that just lists common shortcuts quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, save the cheatsheet.gif somewhere on your computer.

On Windows (largely taken from ['How to easily open files and URLs from the [windows] command-line'](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html) and ['Execute external programs asynchronously under Windows'](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows)), you can use this ex command:

```
:!start cmd /c start C:\path\to\cheatsheet.gif
```

To turn this into a keymap, use something like:

```
:nnoremap <f5> :!start cmd /c start C:\path\to\cheatsheet.gif
```

To make it permanent, put that line in your vimrc (`:e $MYVIMRC`), but don't include the colon at the very start of the line.

On Linux:

```
:!xdg-open /path/to/cheatsheet.gif &
:nnoremap <f5> :!xdg-open /path/to/cheatsheet.gif &
```

I can't recall off the top of my head what the OSX command for 'open with default application' is, but the vim command would just replace `xdg-open` with whatever that is.

---

All of these just open cheatsheet.gif with the default program you have set up for GIF images. See `:h !` and (for Windows) `:h !start`.

Answer (score 2):

No need for an external cheatsheet:

```
:viusage
:exusage
```

and:

```
:h quickref
```

Comment: While I much prefer having something internal, these are still too long to use for a quick reference. But great for when I'm working over ssh.